# Checking existence of list of python values in psycopg2/postgresql

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2, postgresql-9.0

I have a python list of values and a postgresql table with a certain column in it.  I'd like to know for each element in my python list whether there is any row in the table with that ID.

For example, suppose I have this python list:

```
vals = [4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42]
```

and also that the query:

```
select my_col from my_table;
```

gives:

```
[4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Then I'd like a query that returns:

```
[True, True, False, False, False, False]
```

I could loop through the list and execute a new "select exists" for each value, but I wondered if there was a way to do it in a single call?

I am restricted to postgresql 9.0

Comment: Why not just use 2 lines of Python after the `select`?  One to make that result into set `s`, then just `[x in s for x in vals]`?

Comment: So pull the entire DB column into python?  That would work.  It's going to have a few hundred million entries at some point so not sure if that would be a little bad for performance?  (The column will be indexed.)

Comment: The example there is just for illustration - I'm not really selecting the full column in my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is more about SQL than aboyt Python or psycopg. I'd use a query like:

```
SELECT my_col = ANY(your_array_here) FROM my_table;
```

to get result in "table order" or:

```
SELECT A.x = ANY(SELECT my_col FROM my_table) 
  FROM (SELECT * FROM unnest(your_array_here) x) A;
```

to get the result in "vals order".

Fortunately enough psycopg provides a default adapter that converts Python lists to PostgreSQL arrays and the code is extremely simple:

```
curs.execute("SELECT my_col = ANY(%s) from my_table", (vals,))
```

or:

```
curs.execute("""SELECT A.x = ANY(SELECT my_col FROM my_table) 
                  FROM (SELECT * FROM unnest(%s) x) A""", (vals,))
```

Note that the bound variable argument should be a `dict` or a tuple and you want to bind the full list to a single variable in the query, meaning that you should use a 1-element tuple (`(vals,)`) instead of trying to pass `vals` directly.

Comment: This is perfect - many thanks.  And you're right this is more a sql question!

Answer (score 1):

I think this requires a mix of string formatting and placeholders (because you need one `%s` per item in `vals`):

```
vals = [4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42]

query = 'select distinct(my_col) from my_table where my_col in ('
query += ', '.join(['%s'] * len(vals))
query += ')'

cursor.execute(query, vals)
theset = {t[0] for t in cursor.fetchall()}

theboollist = [v in theset for v in vals]
```

This approach should guarantee that the amount of data you're sending to the DB (for the `where ... in` clause) and the amount you're getting back from it are both `O(N)` where `N` equals `len(vals)`; I think it would be logically impossible to do better than that in big-O terms.

Comment: Would it help to use `select distinct my_col` to guarantee `len(cursor.fetchall()) <= N`?

Comment: @unutbu sure, if duplications are possible in `my_col` -- hadn't considered that case, now editing to fix, tx.