# Check python array (or csv) for duplicates in PostgreSQL, display the status in the adjacent column

Tags: python, sql, database, postgresql, duplicates

I have input data in python:

| First_Name | Last_Name | Location |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Pennie | Moore | Santa Clara,CA,USA |
| Paul | Lapointe | Torrance,CA,USA |
| Travis | Day | San Jose,CA,USA |
| Kiva | Dale | Boise Metropolitan Area |
| Michael | Goss | Fredericksburg,VA,USA |

DB stores data in same format.

I need a query that checks if that data exist in PostgreSQL DB, and display the duplicate status (yes or no) in the adjacent column, like that

(Python array `[{"First_Name": "Pennie", "Last_Name": "Moore", "Location": "Santa Clara, CA, USA"}, {"First_Name": "Kiva", "Last_Name": "Dale", "Location": "Boise Metropolitan Area"}]` )

| First_Name | Last_Name | Location | Duplicates |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Pennie | Moore | Santa Clara,CA,USA | yes |
| Paul | Lapointe | Torrance,CA,USA | no |
| Travis | Day | San Jose,CA,USA | no |
| Kiva | Dale | Boise Metropolitan Area | yes |
| Michael | Goss | Fredericksburg,VA,USA | no |

Input data can be represented as csv or simple list of jsons
`[{"First_Name": "Pennie", "Last_Name": "Moore", "Location": "Santa Clara, CA, USA"}, {...}, ..]`

Not necessary but desirable that First and Last names from list will be searched IN (not EQUALS) the same values in DB (e.g. Dan is containing in Daniel)

So far I tried concating first+last names +location, and searching by the same way of concating column in DB, but on large volumes I am receiving big delay.

Also I found [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27846033/checking-existence-of-list-of-python-values-in-psycopg2-postgresql), but the solution only helps when searching by one column, and not considering WORD CONTAINS.

Answer (score 3):

After you insert the data then you may check for duplicates.
To do this group by (first_name, last_name, location) as a record value.

```sql
select first_name,
       last_name,
       location, 
       case when count(1) > 1 then 'yes' else 'no' end as duplicates
  from _table
 group by (first_name, last_name, location);
```

Comment: Thank you! I do not need to insert the data to a table, I only need to check if the data from python array (list) exist in DB table.

Comment: In that case, you may learn some pandas basics and functionality. => https://thispointer.com/pandas-find-duplicate-rows-in-a-dataframe-based-on-all-or-selected-columns-using-dataframe-duplicated-in-python/